# How to validate a listbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I have a listbox and I want to validate it, if the user clicks on submit button without selecting any value from the listbox.
Right now I am doing as below but I am not able to see the validation message.Where am I going wrong?

aspx:

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ddList" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="125" Style="background: none;"></asp:ListBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RQddList" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddList" InitialValue="" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

cs:

```
if (ddList.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                if(ddList.SelectedIndex == -1)
                {
                    RQddList.Text = "* requires value";
                }
            }
```

Comment: Try providing default value `<asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text=""></asp:ListItem>` and check if the selected value is still this.

Comment: @HassanImam listbox is dynamically getting loaded from the cs page, I cannot hardcode the value

Answer (score 1):

Html

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
   <asp:ListItem Value="1">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem  Value="2" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem  Value="3" ></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem  Value="4" ></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="select listitems" 
            ControlToValidate="ListBox1" InitialValue="" EnableTheming="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" ViewStateMode="Enabled">

        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

         <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
```

If you facing this error:

> Error : WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for jquery. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

Add this in you web config and refer the below links,

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Try this it will help you,

[Refer this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a) [link2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/error-webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-script/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, use the following code.

```
protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ddList.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

And on Submit button check if the ddList.SelectedIndex is not -1. If it is still -1, display error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?
What is the initial value of selectedIndex in the submit button?

Comment: I am not getting an error, but I am not able to see the validation message also

Comment: Try this validation `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqDropDownList" controltovalidate="ddList" errormessage="Please select an item!" />`

Comment: did that but still I am not able to see any validation message

Comment: Try adding `ErrorMessage="Required"` as property of required field validator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145416/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-sumedha).